# Ошибка в коде Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Нужно доработать код что бы он обрабатывал "одновременно" вот такого плана текст (Текст между символами может быть разным).

Текст до обработки:

```
TEST "111111> TEST1 TEST "111111> TEST1 TEST "111111> TEST1
TEST """111111> TEST1 TEST """111111> TEST1 TEST """111111> TEST1
TEST """222222>> TEST2 TEST """222222>> TEST2 TEST """222222>> TEST2
TEST """333>>> TEST3 TEST """333>>> TEST3 TEST """333>>> TEST3
TEST "444444>>> TEST4 TEST "444444>>> TEST4 TEST "444444>>> TEST4 TEST "444444>>> TEST4
TEST ""5555>>> TEST5 TEST ""5555>>> TEST5
```

Результат, после обработки должен быть вот в таком виде:

```
TEST TEST1 TEST TEST1 TEST TEST1
TEST TEST1 TEST TEST1 TEST TEST1
TEST TEST2 TEST TEST2 TEST TEST2
TEST TEST3 TEST TEST3 TEST TEST3
TEST TEST4 TEST TEST4 TEST TEST4 TEST TEST4
TEST  TEST5 TEST TEST5
```

П/C: Обработка из файла и сохранение в файл.

Comment: Если с мемо работает то очевидно, что проблема с записью или чтением в/из файла

Comment: Не подскажите как исправить ?

Comment: В основной теме указала правильно условия конкурса. Точнее в правильном виде.

Comment: Это не ответы "не являются исчерпывающими", а вопрос мутирует так, что ответы перестают на него отвечать.

Comment: @Igor, Ваши ответы были верны и мне помогли. Но просто по надобности изменила тему так как теперь нужно вот такое конкурсное решение. С Уважением Татьяна.

Comment: @Татьяна Это неправильно. Вопрос был задан и получил правильный ответ. Если вопрос теперь другой, то он должен быть задан, как новый вопрос.

Comment: @Igor, когда я задаю похожие вопросы то тогда меня все критикуют. Похожие в плане код один и тот же а изменить нужно что то другое - в нем. То как тогда в таком случае поступать ?

Comment: @Татьяна Я Вас только хвалил :). Выше - это мое мнение. В данном случае я считаю, что отличий достаточнo для задания нового вопроса.

Comment: @Igor, Да, хвалили я знаю :), Вас я не имела в виду. Может поможете решить этот вопрос и тему как раз закроем. Плиззз...

Comment: @Igor, Ну, коль никто не откликнулся в конкурсе то справедливо награду отдаю Вам . Мне для хорошего человека не жалко. Кстати задачу я уже сегодня решила.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for P := Len downto 1 do 
begin
  if S[P] = '"' then 
  begin
    if Pos1 = 0 then 
    begin
      Pos1 := P;
    end
    else 
    begin
      Delete(S, P, Pos1 - P + 1); // счетчик цикла здесь P, а не i 
      Pos1 := 0;
    end;
  end;
end;
writeln(ft2,s)
```

*Update*

> Как сделать удаление по разным символам. К примеру от знака " до знака >.

```
for P := Len downto 1 do 
begin
  if (S[P] = '>') and (Pos1 = 0) then 
  begin
    Pos1 := P;
  end;
  if (S[P] = '"') and (Pos1 <> 0) then 
  begin
    Delete(S, P, Pos1 - P + 1);
    Pos1 := 0;
  end;
end;
writeln(ft2,s)
```

Comment: Если так делаю то за дублирует по много раз каждую строку и не удаляет.

Comment: Igor, как всегда Огромнейший +.

Comment: @Татьяна Вы увидели, в чем была ошибка?

Comment: Игорь, Да, я неправильно делала, нужно было Pos1 := P; Так же ошибки в условиях если и Delete. Саму логику я поняла и благодаря вам разобралась. Я всегда перед тем как использовать данный мне код изучаю его, и в блокноте пишу для себя, типа шпаргалки, все условия и их логику. Таким способом потихоньку набиваю опыт.

Comment: еще вопрос: А как удалить между символами 'Пример текста'. Сейчас код удаляет между "", то есть  "Пример текста".  Когда добавляю в код if S[P] = ''' then то так ошибка.

Comment: Все разобралась с предыдущим вопросом.

Comment: Интересует еще один вопрос по вашему коду: Как добавить условие что бы удалялся только текст между указанными символами, а сами символы, между которыми идет удаление - оставались?.

Comment: @Татьяна `Delete(S, P + 1, Pos1 - P - 1);`

Comment: Оказывается это еще проще чем я думала. Я делала постоянно Delete(S, P - 1, Pos1 - 1) вот в этом была ошибка хотя логики в моем случае нет. Все получилось, всегда благодарна Вам за помощь.

Comment: @Татьяна Программирование вообще проще, чем многие думают :).

Comment: Igor, Последний вопрос который интересует по вашей функции. Сначала пробовала сама. Как сделать удаление по разным символам. К примеру от знака " до знака >.

Comment: @Татьяна Не "нашей", а "Вашей" :). Сейчас.

Comment: Igor, все разобралась. Все работает отлично, приятного рабочего дня.

Comment: Ну, коль никто не откликнулся в конкурсе то справедливо награду отдаю Вам @Igor.  Мне для хорошего человека не жалко. Кстати задачу я уже сегодня решила.

Answer (score 1):

Уберите строку `Append(ft2);`, т.к. файл только что создается и нету смысла использовать эту команду. Скорее всего это и есть причиной проблемы, потому что идет попытка повторно открыть уже открытый файл

Comment: `Append`, конечно, не нужен, но дело не в нем.

Comment: Не то что мне жалко очков, но этот ответ не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме автора вопроса.

Comment: @Igor, раз человек написал, что при использовании memo у него всё работает, то я рассматривал только вариант с проблемой записью/считывания в файл. И это единственная ошибка, которую я заметил. Но так получилось, что я ошибся.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно мой код не сильно быстрый но за то работает:

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var s : string;
      p1, p2 : integer;
    begin
     ..........................
      p1 := Pos('"', s);
      while p1>0 do begin
        p2 := PosEx('>', s, p1);
        if p2<1 then Break;
        while (p2<Length(s)) and (s[p2+1]='>') do Inc(p2);
        Delete(s, p1, p2+2-p1);
        p1 := Pos('"', s);
      end;
   ................................
    end;
```